# Cuando y porque usar base de datos en Aplicaciones Moviles

Tags: android, base-de-datos, ionic

Sé que esto no es una pregunta en concreto, que se basa en opiniones pero no halle mejor manera de saber o entender el por que y cuando ocupar una base de datos dentro de una aplicación móvil.

Trabajo en muchas aplicaciones nativas en Android e híbridas con Ionic framework, y en la mayoría de las aplicaciones híbridas que he hecho he trabajado sin base de datos, sólo ocupando services, factories, que me ayudan con el localStorage y múltiples validaciones para poder lograr cierta "persistencia" dentro de mi aplicación.

Hace muy poco participé en un curso de Xamarin en el cual nos enseñaron a usar los servicios web de Microsot Azure, donde la mayoria de las aplicaciones se alimentaban de datos en formato JSON y no una base de datos relacional como SQL como se manejaba tradicionalmente con Microsoft.

Por otro lado, todas las aplicaciones que he realizado de forma nativa las he trabajado con base de datos porque ademas de consumir servicios web, existe una lógica diferente de los tratamientos que se le hacen a los datos para manejar y enviar nuevamente al servidor si es el caso. Ahora bien, se que al decir:

> Base de datos porque ademas de consumir servicios web, existe una lógica diferente de los tratamientos que se le hacen a los datos para manejar y enviar nuevamente al servidor

respondo un poco mi pregunta, pero quiero saber qué es lo correcto en este caso, si será correcto cargar el localStorage con datos para buscar y acceder a ellos o es recomendable siempre utilizar una base de datos para hacer la persistencia.

Vuelvo a insistir, se que no es una pregunta en concreto, que quizás no haya un error de por medio pero a experiencia suya me gustaría orientarme respecto a esta inquietud.

Comment: me suena de haber respondido a una pregunta similar, donde detallaba los usos de cada sistema de base de datos.

Comment: @Webserveis voy a buscar esa respuesta!

Comment: prueba aquí si te responde tus dudas: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20703/almacenamiento-en-base-de-datos-en-android-e-ios-con-cordova/21113#21113

Comment: Añado si tu app es solo lectura, como una guia de viaje, yo utilizaría base de datos offline, con un sistema de sincronización cuando detecte internet para actualizar datos.

Comment: claro, la aplicación que estoy construyendo ahora (por eso me surgio la duda) es asi, solo lectura y muestra datos, hasta ahora utilizo localStorage pero cuando hay internet actualizo mi key y su valor... Voy a empezar a averiguar bien de esto

Comment: Mirate BD realm con gson puedes volcar directamente a el. Una app que hace poco que la renovado uso eso 100% offline https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.descubrirosona.lite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría que no trataras de usar el localStorage como una base de datos. ¿Por qué? Primero, porque no puedes asumir que funcionará al 100%. De acuerdo a [este artículo](http://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/) y que a su vez dirige al [foro oficial de Ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/localstorage-is-it-cleared-after-app-restarts-periodically-in-ios/21819/9) existen ciertos bugs en ambas grandes plataformas (iOS y Android). Además, hay un límite que *creo* es de 10MB. Además, tendrías que manejar serializaciones, búsquedas, etc., **dentro de un string**. Hay alternativas como [PouchDB](http://www.ion-book.com/tips/pouchdb) que trabaja con JSON o [mismos plugins de Córdova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/latest/cordova/storage/database/database.html) .

**EDIT**

Tal vez dije cosas que ya sabías pero bueno, aceptaste que tu pregunta está todavía un poco al aire. Trataré de hondear.

> ¿Cuándo y por qué usar una base de datos en Aplicaciones Móviles?

**Depende de tu tipo de aplicación**

Hay apps que hacen todo el trabajo en el front, otras sólo son una vista que refleja el backend. Para unas necesitas persistencia de datos. Para otras no. Eso lo terminas decidiendo tú. Si piensas comercializar tu app en algún momento tendrás que implementarla en el backend y por eso el tutorial tiene una sección de Azure Services. Si tu app requiere información sensible del usuario, aún más. Ahora, no significa que todo lo debas guardar en el front. De hecho todas las tareas de autenticación y verificación tienen que caer del lado del servidor porque es lo que único que puedes controlar al 100% por razones que creo todos conocemos.

Después considera: ¿quieres depender de que cuando el usuario necesite algún dato tenga que hablarle a tu backend o prefieres ciertos datos guardados? Si es sólo un string o una lógica que no significa mucho, usa el localStorage. Si es uno o más objetos sensibles, es mejor optar por una base de datos o un archivo de configuración simple.

**Detalle que olvidé mencionar y no está muy claro en muchos tutoriales**

> sólo puedes guardar strings en el localStorage

por eso mencionaba la serialización. Espero haberte aportado algo más con esto.