# Base de datos alternativas para Android

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, android-sqlite

Estoy realizando un nuevo proyecto que anteriormente estaba en Windows Mobile. Ahora intento migrar el mismo a la plataforma Android, pero tengo un inconveniente en la parte de base de datos:

en C# utilizaba SQL Server para almacenar datos de manera local, y en Android tengo que usar SQLite, pero necesito usar stored procedures y SQLite no lo soporta.

Quisiera saber si puedo tener alguna alternativa de base de datos para poder usar de manera local los stored procedures.

Comment: Por norma general el 99% de los casos en los que se usa una base de datos de manera local se pueden sustituir los procedimientos almacenados por código en la aplicación (y posiblemente el otro 1% también se pueda pasar a código de manera más o menos compleja).

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Heisenberg si bien esta pregunta está orientada a Cordova, probablemente la encuentres útil [Almacenamiento en base de datos en Android e iOS con Cordova](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20703/127)

Comment: @Mariano puede que no se necesite código para que se intuya lo que quiere que le respondamos, pero un ejemplo de lo que quiere de entrada y salida no sobraría. Tampoco sobraría que ganara la medalla [Informado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed?userid=19623) haciendo el [Recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y sepa cómo funciona el sitio antes de publicar nada. Yo lo hice en su día.

Comment: @Mariano gracias por tu respuesta, esa era la informacion que estaba buscando, Awes0meM4n, e usado la version en ingles se mas o menos como funciona solo que era una pregunta de la cual no necesitaba codigo solo una respuesta como la de Mariano, gracias Saludos

Comment: @Awes0meM4n en eso obviamente tenés toda la razón ;-) (más allá de lo que contestó el autor). Lo comenté principalmente porque no pensaba que estuviera para cerrarse (y muchas veces esos comentarios terminan cerrando la pregunta)

Comment: @Heisenberg06 Si esa respuesta responde a tu pregunta, podemos cerrarla como duplicada (sino, por favor no dudes en comentar qué faltaría)

Comment: @Heisenberg06 Ya que hablas de experiencia en otros sitios de Stack Exchange veo que tienes cuenta en el sitio inglés, que tampoco allí has hecho el tour y que sólo has aceptado una pregunta de las 10 que has hecho allí. Deberías de preocuparte más por participar en la comunidad, sobretodo de aceptar las respuestas que te han dado y marcar tus preguntas como respondidas. Es bueno para ti y para la comunidad que te ayudó.