# Usabilidad offline en aplicación con PhoneGap/Cordova en nativo

Tags: cordova, phonegap

Estoy haciendo una aplicación usando Phonegap-Cordova. Necesito guardar una gran  cantidad de datos en una base de datos (500-800Mb) para que la aplicación funcione offline de forma que se sincronice con un servidor cuando el dispositivo recupere la conexión a Internet y mande los datos guardados
offline al servidor. He visto que tenemos varias opciones:

1. **Webstorage**,  solo guarda 50Mb
2. Usar algun plugin **SLQlite**   a[parentemente también tiene limite de espacio](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/)
3. Guardar de forma **nativa**

Por lo que he leído, hacerlo de forma nativa es la más versátil, pero no encuentro ejemplos de como implementarlo.
Por favor, alguien me puede poner algún ejemplo de como implementarlo o mandarme algún enlace, ya he visto que hay [una solución aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20703/almacenamiento-en-base-de-datos-en-android-e-ios-con-cordova), pero **no** hace referencia a guardar en nativo

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Almacenamiento en base de datos en Android e iOS con Cordova](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20703/almacenamiento-en-base-de-datos-en-android-e-ios-con-cordova)

Comment: Gracias pero pregunto por guardar en nativo , localStorage ,WebSQL, IndexedDB , conSQLite (via plugin)  no me sirven

Comment: @JeCuRo a que te refieres cuando dices: **Guardar en forma nativa** ???

Comment: Me refiero a guardar los datos usando el sdk nativo de Android e iOS